# What are these codes on game covers?

Tags: xbox-360

I'm organizing a large number of console video games and I was wondering what these codes on game covers stand for and what is the purpose to have them?

[image: Codes on Package]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In essence, those are unique IDs for each game - at least the PS3 ones. I can't currently find any sources about the X360 ones.

## PlayStation 3

Various communities, single users and random sites try to collect these (I couldn't find an actual comprehensive list, though).

[One in particular](http://www.sonyindex.com/index.htm) also largely explains the naming scheme:

- **ES** stands for the European sales region
- **US** for the NA region
- **JM**, **JS**, **AS** and probably a bunch of others stand for various Asian regions

As per @TML's comment:

- The **BC** prefix is used for first-party content by Sony and subsidaries.
- The **BL** prefix, on the other hand, for third-party content.

So, a BCES is a first-party game released to the European market.

## It's a unique ID for each released retail version of a game.

And, as pointed out in the comments, it is mostly referred to as a "title ID". "catalogue number" or similar. On consoles, these are usually used to identify game data on the hard disk (savegames and the such).

Comment: You mean unique to the DISC or unique to the GAME?

Comment: Unique to the game. Well, not even that. As far as my research showed, apparently re-releases (f.e. updated versions) sometimes get a different ID. And, obviously, different regions get different IDs. But it is *not* a disc-unique ID.

Comment: A bit more info about the PS3 catalog numbers:

  BCES: Sony first-party product released to European markets
  BLES: Third-party product, European markets
  BCUS: Sony first-party product released to American markets

...and so on. I don't know anything about the XBOX 360 cataloging system, though.

Comment: The term usually used in the industry for this number is the _title ID_ and sometimes retailers call it a _catalog number/ID_; you can find them on all platforms, not just the Xbox 360 and PS3 and not just on retail boxes. Digital-only games also have them because they are usually what identifies save files, achievement lists, etc.